# How can I optimize this query with subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT value_1, (
    SELECT value_4 
    FROM table_1
    WHERE value_3 < value_1 
    ORDER BY value_3 DESC  
    LIMIT 1
)
AS result_value 
FROM table_2 
WHERE value_1 BETWEEN 1325372400000 AND 1328050800000  
ORDER BY value_1
```

Which returns 32 results and takes 6.6 seconds to run. The idea is to get the entries from table_1 where value_3 is "closest" to value_1 in table_2.

The two queries the query is comprised of, namely

```
SELECT value_1
AS result_value 
FROM table_2 
WHERE value_1 BETWEEN 1325372400000 AND 1328050800000  
ORDER BY value_1
```

and (for example)

```
SELECT value_4 
FROM table_1
WHERE value_3 < 1328050800000 
ORDER BY value_3 DESC  
LIMIT 1
```

each take 0.03 seconds to run. Computing the accumulated time for 32 result sets, the compound query should take no longer than 1 second, or probably even less (because I/O overhead for individual queries is not accounted for). Yet at 6.6 seconds, it takes much longer.

Why is that, how can I optimize it? Or is there another/superior way to reach my goal?

**Update:**

Table definitions:

table_1 (MyISAM, 700000 entries):

```
'id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
'value_3', 'bigint(20) unsigned', 'NO', 'UNI', '0', ''
'value_4', 'bigint(20) unsigned', 'NO', '', '0', ''
```

table_2 (MyISAM, 4000 entries):

```
'value_1', 'bigint(20) unsigned', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, ''
```

EXPLAIN [query]:

```
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'table_2', 'range', 'PRIMARY,value_3_UNIQUE', 'PRIMARY', '8', NULL, '32', 'Using where; Using index'
'2', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'table_1', 'index', 'value_3,value_3_value_4', 'value_3', '8', NULL, '1', 'Using where'
```

Comment: what indexes do you have on the tables?

Comment: Do you have a `(value3)` index on `table_1`? Or a `(value3, value4)`?

Comment: Can you add the tables' definitions? How many rows do the tables have?

Comment: Your generic "Values" dont give us a true context of what you want.  The answer might be approaching your query in a completely different way.  And if some sample data showing the context (limited, and only those columns to get the point through) sometimes help too.

Comment: I have indices value_1 on table_2, value_3 and (value_3, value_4) on table_1.

Comment: The EXPLAIN output is what I posted.

Comment: I'm sorry, you probably meant the EXPLAIN output for the query. That I now have posted too.

Comment: @Maximilian: Are you sure you select only those 2 columns? And the Where condition has only `table2.value_1`? Or is the query more complex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bit of mysql kung fu:

```
SELECT * from
(SELECT value_1, value_4
FROM table_2 
join table_1 on value_3 < value_1
WHERE value_1 BETWEEN 1325372400000 AND 1328050800000  
ORDER BY value_1, value_3 DESC) x
GROUP BY value_1 
ORDER BY value_1
```

The "kung fu" is that with mysql when the columns you're not grouping by are not aggregated (eg `SUM()` etc), you get the *first* row encountered for each group. If you use this technique on an ordered result set, you can get the value you're after.

Not only is this easier to code, but you'll notice that just one pass is made over the tables (not one query per row as you tried). It should perform well.

#### Edit:

There has been conjecture by some commenters that this special form of `GROUP BY` is "indeterminate" and/or "not officially supported" etc. The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) states that the row selected in "indeterminate", however I have never seen nor heard of mysql selecting any row *other* than the first encountered and using an `order by` on the inner select is used and relied upon in countless production queries.

FWIW, I am happy to recommend this approach as being "reliable" and production-worthy.

Comment: This may result in ordering a very big derived table.

Comment: Is this guaranteed to return the right rows in all cases, since you rely on MySQL to return the first row completely in each group. As I understand this is not necessarily the case it is basically up to MySQL to return arbitrary values for each of the attributes as long as they belong to the group?!

Comment: @ypercube yeah true. Note to OP: Because you've got a range (not a match), the number of rows is unbounded. If this query sucks, it sucks. You'll have to try another way. It all depends on the number of rows and available system resources

Comment: @stryba: The query will work fine (giving correct results). At least until you update MySQL and the query optimizer code has been changed (on how the `GROUP BY` works). And then this query will break :)

Comment: @stryba Yes, but the group by trick is being done on the result of the inner *ordered* query, so results are predicable.

Comment: @Bohemian: And you don't really need the last `ORDER BY value_1`. You can write `GROUP BY value_1 ASC` to make it clear.

Comment: @ypercube I left that in because it was in the original query. I'm not sure it isn't still needed if you care about final row order. I've never tested the effect of group by on row order - it probably isn't needed. Maximilian: You may be able to remove the last 'order by'

Comment: @ypercube, Bohemian: I understand that it works at least on your testing machine right now but since it is not guaranteed I wouldn't consider this a general solution though (hence the Kung Fu part I guess)

Comment: @stryba No - you can be confident this works on all mysql servers. I used to get upset that mysql "didn't follow the standard". Now I accept it and use these little non-standard tricks, which by the way are very handy. Here's another trick for you: `UPDATE TABLE SET X=Y LIMIT 100`... yes it updates the first 100 rows it finds, then stops. Completely non-deterministic, but really handy if you want to batch your updates say 10000 rows at a time (instead of all 100M at once and blow your logs)

Comment: This query takes 40 seconds, much longer than the original one.

Comment: If I remove the last "ORDER BY" as suggested, it takes 23 seconds.

Comment: Ouch. The only way to improve it would be to narrow down the number of hits that match the join. Currently it's `on value_3 < value_1`, but could you create a valid range, such as `on value_3 between value_1 - 20 and value_1` or similar that you *knew* was always going to be true - it would *really* help the optimizer

Comment: I have tried to use a sensible range per your suggestion but now the query doesn't return any results at all anymore.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It now works, and the query takes 1.5 seconds. Further optimization suggestions welcome.

Comment: [The documentation could not be any clearer that results are indeterminate, not guaranteed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) so even if it does happen to work now I wouldn't use this unless you plan on revisiting it if and when you upgrade.

Comment: This is the answer that brought me substantial performance improvement. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an index on `value_1` in `table_2` and a compound `(value3, value4)` index on `table_1`, then only the indices will be used by the query.

---

You could also try this query:

```
SELECT value_1
     , value_4 AS result_value 
FROM table_2 
  JOIN table_1
    ON table_1.value_3 =
       ( SELECT value_3
         FROM table_1
         WHERE value_3 < value_1 
         ORDER BY value_3 DESC  
         LIMIT 1
       )
WHERE value_1 BETWEEN 1325372400000 AND 1328050800000  
ORDER BY value_1
```

Comment: The compound index I didn't have at first; after adding it now, the query still clocks in at the same 6.6 seconds.

Comment: @Maximilian: Can you add the tables definitions and the EXPLAIN output in the question?

Comment: I have added the table definitions to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here Iam just avoiding use of virtual(derived) table. The main reason behind virtual table usage was sorting which has been achieved by applying order by clause within the groupcconcat().

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(value_1 
                                    ORDER BY value_1, value_3 DESC),',',1) as value_1, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(value_4
                                    ORDER BY value_1, value_3 DESC),',',1) as value_4 
FROM table_2 join table_1 on value_3 < value_1 

WHERE value_1 BETWEEN 1325372400000 AND 1328050800000  

GROUP BY value_1  
ORDER BY value_1
```